# Create MongodbObject using bson.util

Tags: json, mongodb, bson

I have a `JsValue`(`spray.json.JsValue`) which is in `JSON` format. I need to convert this JSON value to a `MongodbObject` using `bson.util`. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You've probably got an answer for this already, but since i was just looking for a way to do the same conversion I thought I'd leave an answer. This worked for me.

You can convert it to a String using spray.json and use the JSON.parse provided by com.mongodb.util.JSON.

The trick is to remove the additional double quotes at the start and end of the string so that JSON.parse recognises it as a json object instead of a JSON String.

```
  import spray.json._
  import DefaultJsonProtocol._

  val json = "{'foo':'baa'}"
  val jsValue = json.toJson

  val slicedJson = jsValue.toString().slice(1, jsValue.toString().length - 1)

  val dbObject = JSON.parse(slicedJson).asInstanceOf[DBObject]
```